# Terminated the Fashion MNST download and now getting error when trying to download again

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras

I had to terminate the Fashion_MNIST download as it was downloading very slowly. When I am trying to download it again I am getting the below error.  I think I need to delete the earlier partial download first. I am not able to find the folder where the partial download is saved in my *Macbook*. Can you please suggest where I can find the partial download in Mac OS?

Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py", line 59, in load_data
    imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_train), 28, 28)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think tensorflow is trying to read already downloaded dataset, in order to download again instead of reading from disk you can delete corrupted files from disk

they are generally located in ~/.keras/datasets/{name}

```
rm -rf ~/.keras/datasets/fashion-mnist/
```